# Ресайз видео в PyQt5 (OpenCV)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, opencv

Мне нужно, чтобы видео изменяло размеры от размеров самого окна. Видео проигрывается в лэйбле, которому стоит правило на заполнение. Но при уменьшении окна видео просто обрезается. Можно ли этого избежать уменьшая само разрешение видео динамически (не запрещая на абсолютный минимайз)
Ниже код функции воспроизведения и правил размеров (без них тоже работает)

```
def video_stream(self):
    ret, frame = self.video_capture.read()
    if not ret:
        return False


    video_width = int(self.video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    video_height = int(self.video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    
    screen_rect = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
    video_width = (screen_rect.width() if video_width > screen_rect.width() else video_width)
    video_height = (screen_rect.height() if video_height > screen_rect.height() else video_height)

    self.video_size = QtCore.QSize(video_width, video_height)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.video_size.width(), self.video_size.height()), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)



    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
    self.frame_lable.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Поставил так
        self.frame_lable.setMinimumSize(10, 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё решилось очень просто

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.frame_lable.size().width(), self.frame_lable.size().height()), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Теперь для ресайза берутся значения размеров виджета

Также для виджета стоит правило

```
self.frame_lable.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```